# Mac Mail sometimes sending my message as attachment rather than as body

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail

I have a Gmail supported business account, but all logins are done through Gmail, and I use Mac Mail on Ventura 13.3.1.

I have had a number of people tell me that sometimes when my mails arrive in their inbox, the message is encoded as an attachment and the body is blank, and sometimes they are unable to open the attachment, or they don't realise it's there and think I sent a email without any content.

Sometimes when sending (not sure if this is related), I get "mac mail unable to verify message signature - there was a problem reading the digital signature for this message"

I have nothing funky in configuration, I simply clicked on "New Account" and used my Gmail credentials.

This is becoming a real problem, as with my business I send out a lot of prospecting emails to sales leads, and I have a feeling many of them don't even read my message because it comes through incorrectly.

Can anyone suggest what I can try to get to the bottom of this?

Below is an image of an email that caused a problem with the sender, as it appears in my sent mail box

[image]

Comment: The problem is the term “sometimes.”  Configurations are static and don’t randomly change so it highly unlikely it’s anything in your part. See if there’s a particular set of recipients that this effects. Also, if forwarding/replying, see if there’s a particular set there, too.

Comment: Have you got a signature? What do you see in your Sent mailbox (do you see the emails as they should normally be?)?

Comment: @Thinkr I do have a signature yeah, it's a combination of image and text. I'll try add a screenshot of how one of the problem emails appears in my sent folder, looks fine to me. The recipient said he got the spreadsheets but no text, on his phone he got it all.

Comment: @Allan The people who seem to notice most are those behind corporate firewalls with policies about external senders. It also seems to affect desktop clients, not mobile ones. I think it causes issues with email structure and displayability to everyone, but depending on what client other people are using, they either notice it or don't. Eg mobile clients seem fine, web gmail fine, but people using corporate outlook are the ones most affected

Comment: Bypass the mail app and log into Gmail directly (web) and send from there.  What are the results?  This will determine whether it’s a gmail or Mail issur

Comment: Thanks, it helps to narrow the problem a bit, so this only happens on Mac. Try to send an email to another account of yours on iPhone and on Mac and see if it also happens. Also awaiting the answer to Allan's comment :)

Comment: @Allan - Sending from web gmail or Mimestream (which I downloaded the other day) both work fine, so it seems to be something to do with Mac mail. I'm just waiting to hear back from someone who had the issue recently with my mail, what client they use. I can send mailt to myself and it reads fine in web gmail, iphone mail and mac mail, but if my MAC mail configuration is causing the issue then that may be why I don't see an issue. I've asked him what client he uses

Comment: That’s good to know.  I have access to an Exchange account so I tested by sending mail both from gmail web and through Apple Mail.  Unfortunately, I couldn’t replicate the problem; it worked every time. Ping me again when you get the results

Comment: @Allan sorry for the delay, they took ages to get back to me. Apparently they used Outlook for Mac, the guy who saw it all screwed up. And I think the other people who saw issues also use Outlook as they were all corporate people behind firewalls, and most companies use Outlook internally